# At what layer should the conversion from Entity Class to DTO Class be handled?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, dao, dto

as it is understood from the title, I am interested in the transformation from Entity Class to DTO Class.
According to my research from Stackoverflow and other sites, if I'm using any ORM tool, DAO Classes should always return Entity Objects. But if I use JDBCTemplate? Or if I use JDBC? Then at what layer should I make the conversion from Entity to DTO? The DAO too? Or is it at the Service Tier? I would appreciate if your answers are technically explanatory.

Comment: Could you provide an example of DTO and Entity? Please. It can be any fake class of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your DTO or model layer will be the one that contains the entities. The DAO or repository layer will handle the CRUD operations through JPA, and it is allowed to interact with DTO/entity objects only. Finally, comes the service or adapter layer which will perform the conversion from DTO to the required other types by calling the methods of the DAO layer.

In the case of JDBC, the DTO layer can act as a POJO layer. I believe that the DAO layer which was based on JPA, can be based on JDBC to perform the queries, build the POJO objects and return them to the service layer. So eventually it's just a replacement of the DAO layer which is based on JPA to be based on JDBC.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I need to handle DTO conversion for JPA on Service Layer, but if I don't use JPA and use JDBCTemplate or if I use JDBC then where should I do this conversion?